# Unable to Send Email Via PHP using SMTP

Tags: php, email, xampp, smtp

This is my email.php file:

```
 <?php

    $to = "someemail@gmail.com";
    $from = "myemail@gmail.com";

    $subject="Email";
      $body="hi";  
    $headers = array(
        'From' => $from,
        'To' =>  $to,
        'Subject' => $subject
        );

             $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
                    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'port' => '465',
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ));
            $mail = $smtp->send( $to, $headers, $body);

            if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
                echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
            } else {
                echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
            }

?>
```

I have enabled access to less secure apps, DisplayUnlockCaptcha as well as IMAP. I have not enabled 2-step verification in the account. However, I still get the following error.

```
authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 i28sm32905934pfk.17 - gsmtp)]
```

I am using XAMPP in Windows and this is what I've put in my php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 465
; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
```

If someone could help me resolve this issue I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: You are signing in within 10 minutes of the time you entered captcha right?

Comment: I am not familiar with xampp. But i hope you have installed php-pear and that mail.php is in your `require` statement

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach using SwiftMailer.

You can easily get the component with a json file and see how that goes.
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html#basic-usage